# Hash Table to find the number that appears the most in a list

Tags: c#, hash

I had my first technical test for an internship today and one of the questions asked was:
Given a list of integers, find the one that appears the most in the list. If 2 or more integers are tied for the most appearances, return the highest one.
I am convinced that the particular problem can be solved in O(n) time by implementing Hash Tables. However, I was unable to come up with working code and ended up with an O(nlogn) solution:

```
        var groups = myList.GroupBy(v => v);
        groups = groups.OrderByDescending(v => v.Count());
        int max = groups.First().Key;
        int maxCounts = groups.First().Count();
        foreach (var group in groups)
        {
            var groupKey = group.Key;
            var counts = group.Count();
            if (counts < maxCounts) break;
            if (groupKey > max) max = groupKey; 
        }
        Console.WriteLine(max);
```

Could someone provide working code, preferably in C# that implements Hash Tables to solve this problem in O(n) time?

Comment: This seems like a question more suited to CodeReview.SE

Comment: LINQ `GroupBy` internally is using hash based implementation. Other then that, there is `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` class.

Comment: That's true, Ivan. But the OrderByDescending method uses quicksort which is an O(nlogn) method.

Comment: Hmm, so you are saying you don't know how to search for a maximum using a single loop? Strange.

Comment: Oh, I get what you mean, Ivan. Sorting the list is totally useless. I guess the tension of the moment got the better of me. Thanks for helping me realize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could fill up a frequency hash table by looping over the array once, then loop over the hash table keeping track of the maximum value and maximum frequency:

```
int[] arr = {1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,3,4};
var frequency = new Dictionary<int, int>();

foreach(var x in arr) 
{
    if(!frequency.ContainsKey(x)) frequency.Add(x, 0);
    frequency[x] += 1;
}

var bestKey = frequency.First().Key;
var bestValue = frequency.First().Value;

foreach(var p in frequency.Skip(1))
{
    if(p.Key > bestKey && p.Value >= bestValue)
    {
        bestKey = p.Key; 
        bestValue = p.Value;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("Key={0}, Value={1}", bestKey, bestValue);
```

[**live wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/GwPj1SDTnOvk8v71)

Comment: That's exactly what I as looking for. Thanks, Vittorio.